# How to add UITextView in a Custom UITableViewCell on StoryBoard

Tags: ios5, storyboard

When I add a UITextView to a custom UITableViewCell on StoryBoard I always receive the error:

bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x7c523c0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding UITextView to custom tableViewCell = Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309991/adding-uitextview-to-custom-tableviewcell-crash)