# Adding UITextView to custom tableViewCell = Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a custom tableview cell, which contains some object UIImageView, UILabel, and a UITextView. All object, except the UITextView works fine, but when I try to change the text on the textView:

```
 myTextView.text = @"Some string";
```

the app crashes with this error:

```
Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

Any suggestion is very appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: it seems like you are trying to update text from a secondary thread, is that the case? Can you add some more code?

Comment: Use performSelectorOnMainThread (NSObject method) to update your UITextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error sounds like you are setting the text property from a code block that is not  executing on the main thread. Check to make sure that any code you have that modifies UIKit objects does so while on the main thread. Example below:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Set text here
            myTextView.text = @"Some string"; 
        });
```